# Set radion button Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

There is  my radion button group:

```
            input(type='radio', name='access', value='1', required) Admin
            input(type='radio', name='access', value='2') User
```

And my script:

```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $('.editlink').on('click', function(){
      var id = $(this).data('id');
      $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: "/fetchdata",
        data: { id:  id },
      }).done(function( data ) {
        $('#id').val(data[0]['_id']);
        $('#username').val(data[0]['username']);            
        $('#password').val(data[0]['password']);                  
        $('input[name=access][value = data[0]['access']').prop('checked', true); // Error
      });
    });
  });
```

How can i set my radio button value with the value in database ?

Comment: You have syntax error, Use `$('input[name=access][value="'+data[0]['access']+'"]')`

Comment: you're welcome, Glad to help....